# Android SlidingLibrary

Tags: android, android-library

I tried to find the problem but to no avail, I added the library according to the instructions

> (LibraryProject isLibrary, and addLibrary in myProject)

and when i start my **Project** i have **Error:**

**Log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    at ru.com.whatyouwant.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
```

And **Activity.class**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //SlidingMenu Line 35
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(10);
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);

    // Initialize ID's
    mText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    pop_up_menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pop_up_menu);
    mFiles = new FileOptions(this);

    //Menu ID's
    menu_save = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pop_up_save);
    menu_save.setOnClickListener(onMenu_save);

    menu_delete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pop_up_delete);
    menu_delete.setOnClickListener(onMenu_delete);



    // Call Popup Menu
    mText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            new PopupMenu(pop_up_menu, MainActivity.this);
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the library project referenced from your app project.
Assuming you have both projects already imported into Eclipse:

> 1) Select your project
>
> 2) Right click, **Properties**
>
> 3) Go to the **Android** section on the left panel list
>
> 4) On the **Library** section, you should see the SlidingMenu library project listed.
>
> 5) Press the **Add...** button, select the **SlidingMenu** project, and press **OK**
>
> 6) Press **OK** again to close your project properties window.
>
> 7) You should be set!

Answer (score 0):

i have met the same question.
there is my solution:

1. right click the project---->Properties----->Java Build Path---->Order and Export, check the jar package which your project added as library.
2. close the eclipse and restart it
3. clean the project
4. the problem solved

although the problem solved, but i did't know the reason why it happens, if somebody knows, please tell me, thanks!